# Chef mysql opscode-cookbooks desn't work: "could not find recipe ruby for cookbook mysql"

Tags: mysql, chef-infra

I'm tring to use https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql
but when I run vagrant provision

could not find recipe ruby for cookbook mysql it returns like this.

```
[2014-04-23T10:13:06+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-04-23T10:13:06+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-04-23T10:13:06+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-04-23T10:13:06+00:00] ERROR: could not find recipe ruby for cookbook mysql

================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound
--------------------------------
could not find recipe ruby for cookbook mysql
```

I found this then added mysql-chef_gem.
https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql/blob/b5072e6ae3bd81b0f6ebec8749f2c2d781271ed9/COMPAT.md

```
knife cookbook site vendor mysql-chef_gem -o cookbook
```

But when I add `recipe[crossplat::default]` in `run_list`, and run `vagrant provision` it returns

```
[2014-04-23T10:15:14+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook crossplat not found. If you're loading crossplat from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3):

There was just a large refactor of the mysql cookbook and that recipe is no longer necessary. You can see the updated usage in the [cookbook's README](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: knife cookbook site vendor database -o cookbooks 

I run this and solved! no need mysql-chef_gem,
thank you sethvargo!

Answer (score 2):

cookbooks/mysql/recipes/default.rb not available for mysql cookbook, you need update the run list "recipe[mysql::server]" or "recipe[mysql::client]"

Comment: Can you please add more details ? What do I have to replace "recipe[mysql::server]" with ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error for a different cookbook:

```
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::RecipeNotFound: could not find recipe my_recipe for cookbook my_cookbook
```

This resulted when I removed my_recipe.rb from under the cookbook at some point and the client still referencing it somewhere.  **The simple solution was to re-add a blank recipe file and re-uploading the cookbook.**  This blog describes the problem in more detail and might have a better solution: https://www.rallydev.com/community/engineering/chef-dependency-solving